# Sending an email on edit at SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, swiftmailer, sonata

So in my UsersAdmin I want to send an email to that user if I confirm his account.(in my case, making `Enabled = true`). I do this in the `configureListFields` function

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('groups')
            ->add('enabled', null, array('editable' => true)) //here
            ->add('locked', null, array('editable' => true))
            ->add('createdAt')
        ;
    }
```

By reading the documentation I think i need to use the batchAction function yes? So I made this:

```
public function getBatchActions()
{
    // retrieve the default batch actions (currently only delete)
    $actions = parent::getBatchActions();
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $user = //how to get the user that i am editing right now?

    if ($this->hasRoute('edit') && $this->isGranted('EDIT')) {
        $body = $container->get('templating')->render('MpShopBundle:Registration:registrationEmail.html.twig', array('user'=> $user));

        $message = Swift_message::newInstance();
        $message->setSubject($container->get('translator')->trans('registration.successful'))
            ->setFrom($container->getParameter('customer.care.email.sender'))
            ->setTo('email@contact.lt')
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
        $container->get('mailer')->send($message);

    }

    return $actions;
}
```

Now I am stuck with two unclear thing with this function:

1. How can I get the current user data hat I want to edit?
2. Am I even going in the right direction? Do I need to override edit or maybe some other function?

**THE SOLUTION**

The best way is to do your login in the postUpdate event, so that everytime you update an object it initiates the functions you want.

```
public function postUpdate($user)
{
    if($user->getEnabled() == true) {

        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();

        $body = $container->get('templating')->render('MpShopBundle:Registration:registrationEmail.html.twig', array('user' => $user));

        $message = Swift_message::newInstance();
        $message->setSubject($container->get('translator')->trans('registration.successful'))
            ->setFrom($container->getParameter('customer.care.email.sender'))
            ->setTo('email@contact.lt')
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
        $container->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: is directly listening for changes on the user entity an Option ? or do you explicitly want to to happen only through the edit option in Sonata ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaB Yes only on the edit option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Saving hooks.](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html)

```
   public function postUpdate($user)
    {
       //code to check if enabled 
       // code to send email    
    }
```

Comment: It Worked! I am accepting your answer and updating my post with the solution for other coders. Thanks!

Comment: @Dominykas55 be aware that every time you update an User entity the code will be triggered .